# Play install referrer tracking using desktop Play Market version

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics, google-play-console, install-referrer

1) I'm using [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) to track install referrers from Google Play.

2) When I catch a Play referrer in my app, I send it on Firebase as action.

3) To debug this feature I've created beta-test version on Play Market for my app and modify the link by adding parameter **utm_source=my-source**

So, when user follows my modified link using android device, logging works correctly.

But if user uses, for instance, PC, he will come to desktop version of Play Market, and **utm_source** will be always equals **google-play**

Can someone explain is this a correct behavior? And if it is, how can I properly track my sources?